# Force dealloc of a property declared with strong

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, memory-management

is there a way I can force a property in a class declared as strong `@property (strong, nonatomic)` to be deallocated?

I received a report from a crash where one of the properties are being deallocated, but then the app is trying to access them from a CompletionBlock in a AFHTTPRequest. But since the property was deallocated, the app crashed.

I was unable to reproduce the scenario so I need something that will allow me to force the property to be deallocated only for testing the scenario.

I tried to use dealloc method but ARC forbid it.

Thanks

Comment: self.property = nil. if it has no other strong reference to it, it will be deallocated.

Comment: This is not causing it to be deallocated, that's why I need to force it. There is something else retaining a reference to it, but I'm not sure what

Comment: then you need to declare as weak reference everything that does not really need the object to function. if you want to "force" dealloc, but you dont know who is retaining is a design issue you need to solve first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "force" deallocation of an object under ARC.  You can, however, (sort of) recommend deletion by assigning any object to nil and not using it in the rest of the scope of a method.  If you're having problems with accessing deallocated objects, then you need precisely the opposite: To retain the owning object so it doesn't deallocate any properties.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to forcefully release the memory assigned in a strong property is setting it to nil.

Means:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *testArray;

testArray = //array return from some method;

testArray = nil; //It'll release the memory associated
```

Answer (score 2):

set nil to that object for forcefully release the memory

ex :

```
@property (nonatomic , strong) NSString *str;

str = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the same problem myself right now.

I had set the obvious reference to nil at several points in my app, still the object would not go away.

The object used timers, which all have a strong reference to the object.  Once I invalidated those, dealloc finally ran!

As everyone else has posted all strong references to an object must be nil to run dealloc.  Also, be absolutely thorough in tracking down those references!